# Roots of $x^p - x -1$ over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

> Let $k$ be a field containing $\mathbb{F}_p$ and let $\alpha$ be a root in $k$ for $x^p -x -1 \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$. Show that the roots in $k$ are $\alpha, \alpha-1, \dots ,\alpha-p+1$.

From a previous exercise, I know that $x^p-x = x(x-1)(x-2)\dots(x-(p-1))$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ but I'm not sure how to use this to deduct the roots of the new polynomial in the larger field $k$.

Please help!

Comment: Just check by computation that all these numbers are roots. After having done this, it is clear that these are the only roots, since there at most $p$ of them a priori.

Comment: Use that $(\alpha+k)^p = \alpha^p + k^p$ and that $k^p = k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An element $\alpha$ is a root, if and only if $\alpha^p - \alpha - 1 = 0$, which is equivalent to
$$\alpha^p - \alpha = 1.$$
Now you know the factorization of $x^p-x$, great. Let's define $f(x) := x^p-x$. Can you show that $f(x) = f(x-1) = f(x-2) = \ldots = f(x-p+1)$ for all $x \in k$? Once you have that, given that you know $f(\alpha) = 1$, you are done.
Hint: Use that $\mathbb{F}_p$ is contained in $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\beta_j=\alpha-j$, where $j \in \{1,2, \ldots ,p-1\}$. Then
\begin{align*}
\beta_j^p-\beta-1&=(\alpha-j)^p-(\alpha-j)-1\\
&=(\alpha^p-j^p)-(\alpha-j)-1\\
&=(\alpha^p-\alpha-1)-(j^p-j)\\
&=0-0.
\end{align*}
The first term is $0$ because $\alpha$ is a root, the second term is $0$ by Fermat's little theorem.